# why atomic does not work with auto varaible

Tags: c++, atomic, auto, stdatomic

I am not sure what is wrong with following statements ,  its giving me compilation errors. Can we not use "auto" with atomic variables?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<future>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  atomic<int> value(10);
  auto   NewValue = value;
}
```

but if I replace "auto" with "int" , it works. Why?

```
int main()
{
  atomic<int> value(10);
  int NewValue = value;
}
```

Compilation error with "auto"

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in Hello (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 F:\3d\C++CodeProject\Hello\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
 F:\3d\C++CodeProject\Hello\main.cpp|11|error: use of deleted function 
 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'|
C:\Program Files 
(x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\atomic|612|note: 
declared here|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: There is no copy constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto` matches the data type on the right-hand side of the assignment.  In this statement:

```
auto NewValue = value;
```

`value` is a `std::atomic<int>`, so `auto` will deduce to `std::atomic<int>`, not to `int` like you are expecting.

IOW, this:

```
auto NewValue = value;
```

Is the same as this:

```
atomic<int> NewValue = value;
```

Which is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) using a copy constructor, but `std::atomic` has a `delete`'d copy constructor, which is exactly what the error message says:

> use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'

`std::atomic` has a [conversion operator for `T`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T), which is why `int NewValue = value;` works.

---

**UPDATE**: if you really want to use `auto` and have it deduce as `int`, you can explicitly cast the `std::atomic` to invoke the conversion operator, eg:

```
auto NewValue = (int) value;
```

or

```
auto NewValue = static_cast<int>(value);
```

Otherwise, use the [`std::atomic::load()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load) method, like [@PeterCordes mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165428/50165529#comment137247061_50165529), eg:

```
auto NewValue = value.load();
```

Comment: And the fix is to use `auto NewValue = value.load();`  or `.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` or whatever order you want.  `relaxed` is good ahead of a `compare_exchange_weak` retry loop.

Answer (score 4):

Atomic variables are not copy constructible: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic (3)

This is what `auto` will attempt to do in this instance.

However, you can cast it down to an `int`, using the `operator int` conversion: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T

Comment: I much prefer `value.load();` which reminds readers the variable is atomic, and uses the value type of the atomic object.  `auto foo = (int)value;` defeats the purpose of using `auto` in the first place.